# Can crawlers update imported tables in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm familiarizing myself with crawlers in AWS Glue. I imported a database catalog from Athena, and would like to crawl the data locations of these tables daily to automatically update their partitions when data is added.

However, my crawlers only seem to create new tables, separate from the ones imported from Athena. They don't seem to update my existing tables. Is there any way to do this? Not seeing any mention of it in their docs.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a custom classifier whose job is to classify the data into separate tables in the data catalogue. You are probably using the default classifiers which do not know how to uniquely identify your schema.

What are classifiers: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html

Comment: A custom classifier is essentially code that you write to classify data into specific groups based on your own custom logic, AWS documentation on how to write such a classsifier is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html

Comment: I don't think that this is relevant - classifier are used to parse the schema

Comment: Correct, tables in this case are the schema tables inside the glue catalogue

Answer (score 1):

I have **not** tested this yet, but try to [update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/update-table.html) the following fields in your imported table:

```
"CreatedBy": "arn:aws:sts::000000000000:assumed-role/YOUR_CLAWLER_ROLE/AWS-Crawler"
"Parameters": {
        "CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion": "1.0",
        "compressionType": "none",
        "UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER": "you_crawler_name_for_this_table",
        "CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion": "1.0"
    }
```

I have skipped properties which are not related to crawler. The idea is to update your table that it looks like "created by crawler". May be after this crawler will updated it. :)

To get full table definition use [get-table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/get-table.html) but keep inmind that this output has little difference from [update-table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/update-table.html)

It would be nice if post your results, because I can not try this in nearest time. :(

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do, is to set **UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER** to the name of your crawler, and the crawler will pick it up from the next time.
Please note that if you have any custom fields defined, they will be removed by the crawler.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? I'm not having any luck even after mocking the target table with dummy values for all of the added crawler parameters.

Comment: I have this unconfirmed feeling that it *may* also be sensitive to the way tables are named. I.e, if your S3 directory is s3://acme-corp-data/tables/some-table-name, then your table needs to be named some_table_name